# How to store a query result into an array using PDO::FETCH_OBJ?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

How is it possible to store result of a query into an array? For example, the following code will produce this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as
>   array in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\php_test\test.php:50 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\php_test\test.php on line 50

```
const PATH_TO_SQLITE_FILE = 'my_db.sqlite';

$pdo = new \PDO("sqlite:" . PATH_TO_SQLITE_FILE);

$queryy = $pdo->query('SELECT Title, Format '
                . 'FROM Objects');


$arr = [];

        while ($row = $queryy->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            $arr[] = [
                'Title' => $row['Title'], // Error occurs here. 
                'Format' => $row['Format']
            ];

        }

//echo $arr[1]->Title;
```

I've been stuck with this issue all morning and I haven't found the solution on Google. I hope someone can pinpoint what I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching an object and then trying to access it as if was an array.  Either fetch an array `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or access the object `$row->Title`.

However, your code could be minimized to this:

```
$queryy = $pdo->query('SELECT Title, Format FROM Objects');

$arr = $queryy->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, the minimized part definitely help to focus on what matter. I'll keep studying this.